# Failed to pull manifest by the resolved digest in JFrog artifactory

Tags: docker, artifactory

When I want to pull an image from remote repository in JFrog artifactory, it give a warning with this contents:

```
WARNING: ⚠️ Failed to pull manifest by the resolved digest. This registry does not
    appear to conform to the distribution registry specification; falling back to
    pull by tag.  This fallback is DEPRECATED, and will be removed in a future
    release.  Please contact admins of https://JFROG_URl ⚠️
```

I tried multiple solutions, for example, clearing the cache and giving it again, but it didn't work.

JFrog Artifactory version: 7.12.6

Thanks for helping.